# What security vulnerabilies should I be wary of for user input into SESSION data over SSL?

Tags: php, security

The only piece of sensitive data is credit card number entered into a text input and stored in session to allow order confirmation. After this page the Session is completely unset.

The entire site is over SSL (no non-SSL pages). What security measures do I need to take otherwise?

Is there a way to encrypt this data within the session or tell the server to refuse any requests for this piece of data outside of locally on the server itself, or is any of this necessary?

Thanks in advance. I try not to ask these open ended questions but am not having much luck searching for explanations on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're storing it in the session, then it's most likely being written out in what boils down to plaintext on the server's drive somewhere, which is a huge violation of PCI standards. Even if your site is absolutely secure, anyone on the server with access to the directory where PHP stores the session files could trivially retrieve anyone's card number from the session files.

Instead of storing it this way, store it in a hidden field in the form. There's no problem with storing the data in the clear on the client-side - it's the user's CC number after all, and SSL takes care of the encryption while it's being transmitted. If you want an added layer of security, you can encrypt the CC using `mcrypt()` before inserting it into the hidden field, then decrypt it when the form's submitted back.

Comment: I dont actually send the full number back to the client so I believe mcrypt will be enough. Cheers.

Comment: On a side note: [`suhosin`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.session.encrypt) does encrypt sessions, and all other kinds of goodness :)